# What's the error in this program?

Tags: c

What's the error in this program?

```
    int checkok(onesquare_board[5][5], int x, int y) {

    if (board [x][y]. color != 0) {
            printf("sorry, another piece here \n");
            return 0;       /*if this is true, then validmove will take the value 0*/
    }
    else {
            return 1;       /*if this is true, then validmove will take the value 1*/
    }
}
```

The error that shows up:
    "expected ')' before '[' token" for the first line.

Comment: Is that your real code? Because `onesquare_board` and `board` are not the same...

Comment: To @cornstalks point, please copy/paste code, don't retype it.

Comment: I did copy and paste @BobKaufman I realize now it was the error of misspelling something in the actual program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an underscore instead of a space in the function declaration.  `onesquare board[5][5]` is what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple syntax errors:

```
int checkok(onesquare_board[5][5], int x, int y) {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- no type given for array
if (board [x][y]. color != 0) {
    ^^^^^^---different variable name used
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is the same error twice. `int checkok(onesquare board[5][5] ...` and then `board [x][y].color`